# Rails Test Won't Pass With uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false } set

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, unit-testing, testing

In my user.rb model, I have:

```
validates :email, presence: true, 
                  format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                  uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

And I have the following test:

```
test "email address uniqueness regardless of case" do
    dup_user = User.new(name: "First Last", email: @user.email.upcase)
    dup_user.save
    assert !@user.valid?
end
```

And that test won't pass. I also tried, `assert !@user.save.valid?` thinking that it would fail on save, but that didn't work either.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be checking if the `dup_user` is valid.

```
test "email address uniqueness regardless of case" do
    dup_user = User.new(name: "First Last", email: @user.email.upcase)
    assert ! dup_user.valid?
end
```

Comment: Ah, good catch! As you can see from my answer below, I've reworked it a bit. Do you have any thoughts on which is better?

Comment: My answer saves a trip to the database. Makes your tests faster. Also `save` runs `valid?` already.

Answer (score 2):

Here is what I ended up doing:

In my user.rb model, I have:

```
 validates :email, presence: true, 
                      format: { with: VALID_EMAIL_REGEX },
                      uniqueness: { case_sensitive: false }
```

And I have the following test and setup:

```
def setup
    @user = User.new(name: "John Doe", email: "example@example.com",
             password: "foobar", password_confirmation: "foobar")
    @user.save 
end

test "email address uniqueness regardless of case" do
  dup_user = User.new(name: "First Last", email: @user.email.upcase)
  assert !dup_user.save
end
```

In short what I was doing is passing a user object to be evaluated as true, instead of the save piece. If you do object.save.valid? You're not asking if the save is valid, instead your asking is the object.save returned a valid object, which what is returned from object.save is false (and not an object).